# Ubuntu 20.04, no user found in settings menu as well unlock button not found

Tags: users, 20.04

[image]After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, I am unable add user. In settings >> users there is error message "No user found".

As well unlock button under user menu is also not visible. I have attached screen shot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, close settings, then fire up a terminal.

Enter the following commands and then it should work:

```
sudo service accounts-daemon start
sudo systemctl enable accounts-daemon.service
```